# Touching Base (Checkered Fillomino)

Tags: logical-deduction, word, grid-deduction

This is a [Checkered Fillomino](https://logic-puzzle.fandom.com/wiki/Checkered_Fillomino) puzzle, with the following rules (adapted from the linked page):

- All numbers on the grid must be part of a polyomino of the same value.
- No two polyominoes of the same value can touch horizontally or vertically.
- Givens may be part of the same polyomino, conversely not all final polyominoes may start with a given.
- It must be possible to use two colors to shade the polyominoes so that no bordering polyominoes are the same color.
  [image]

[Solve on Penpa+](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/#m=solve&p=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&a=PZDBucYgCAR78exBRPO/1JIv/beRnQ15JwZYkeW62hw9ovU2Z8XsB+F804yK0+V8u/lX1VKtGrLC7TV7En5VLdUe7u5wdx9V9ay7Xy0Gn2mUqjHYR7k5xcrNq8fYL6P9NPTnx+il+xhvZi2C33/W1zA1DJs1I0vDOw5gljZlyCwtJ4DRcgaztJxCfOopdkBtgBuQ5ZWC8oCXdt8P)

**The answer is a word.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hi
>  [image: Hi]
>  Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 2.